# Move System.Windows.Shapes.Path in C# in string presentation

Tags: c#, .net, path, move

I have string presentation of some `Path`. I want to move path object in string presentation. For example I move `"M 10,100 C 100,0 200,200 300,100"` on `(5, 0)` and get `"M 15,100 C 105,0 205,200 305,100"`. There is standart method for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to define all coordinates in the path relative to the current point, by using the lowercase version of the commands:

```
"M 100,0 c 0,0 200,200 300,100"
```

this way you only need to change the initial Move coordinates and the entire shape will be affected.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built in or "standard".

You will need to parse the string (or deserialize it), make the updates and output the result.